# chromedriver NullPointerException error on linux

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently learning selenium. I have followed a step by step walkthrough on how to start selenium-chromedriver. However I am experiencing this error here and I am have no idea how to solve it.

[image: NullPointerException]

The following are the source code the walkthrough has given me.

```
package driverUtilities;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class DriverUtilities {
    private static DriverUtilities instanceOfDriverUtilities;
    private WebDriver driver;

    public static DriverUtilities getInstanceOfDriverUtilities() {
        if (instanceOfDriverUtilities == null) {
            instanceOfDriverUtilities = new DriverUtilities();
        }
        return instanceOfDriverUtilities;
    }

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        if (driver == null) {
            CreateDriver();
        }
        return driver;
    }

    private String GetDriverName() {
        Properties config = new Properties();
        String driverName = "";
        try {
            config.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Config file is not present");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error when loading config file");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (String key : config.stringPropertyNames()) {
            if (key.equals("browser")) {
                driverName = config.getProperty(key);
            }
        }
        return driverName;
    }

    private void CreateDriver() {
        String driverName = GetDriverName();

        switch (driverName) {
        case "Google Chrome":
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");
            this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
            break;
        case "Firefox":
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "geckodriver.exe");
            this.driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Driver Utilities class

```
package test;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import driverUtilities.DriverUtilities;

public class Mod08_Slide_16_Navigation_Commands {
    @Test
    public void navigationCommands() {
        DriverUtilities myDriverUtilities = new DriverUtilities();
        WebDriver driver = myDriverUtilities.getDriver();

        System.out.println("Start the Test Case");

        // Load the website - http://www.bbc.co.uk
        driver.get("http://www.bbc.co.uk");
        System.out.println("\nLoad the website - http://www.bbc.co.uk");

        // Refresh the page
        driver.navigate().refresh();
        System.out.println("\nRefresh the page");

        // Load the website - http://www.google.co.uk
        driver.get("http://www.google.co.uk");
        System.out.println("\nLoad the website - http://www.google.co.uk");

        // Go back to the website - http://www.bbc.co.uk
        driver.navigate().back();
        System.out.println("\nGo back to the website - http://www.bbc.co.uk");

        // Go forward to the website - http://www.google.co.uk
        driver.navigate().forward();
        System.out.println("\nGo forward to the website - http://www.google.co.uk");

        // Close the browser window
        driver.close();
        System.out.println("\nClose the browser window");

        System.out.println("\nEnd of Test Case \"Navigation Commands\"");
    }
}
```

This is the java test class I am trying to make work of

```
# Change the browser to use for testing purposes, accepted values are Google Chrome and Firefox
browser=Google Chrome
```

I also have the pom.xml file and a config.properties file and will share it if its required.

**Note: My assumptions is that the setproperty function is not locating the correct path to chromedriver. However, I'm a arch linux user thus I'm not sure if the value inside the setproperty function is set to "chromedriver" or "/usr/bin/chromedriver"**

**Note 1: I have navigated to the .metadata of the Eclipse IDE and deleted it after reading some stackoverflow posts. However, this did not work***

**Note 2: I am completely new to Selenium however, I have some experiences with Java and understand that nullpointerexception occurs when I declare a variable but did not create an object and assign that variable to it.**

**Edit 1: I have included the config.properties as specified**

Comment: can you post also your `config.properties` file? Something tells me that's your problem.

Comment: You should also change that property to just "chrome" instead of "Google Chrome".

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion I have is to hard-code the creation of the driver (without `config.properties`) and once you have the code working, you can work on optimizations such as dynamically creating the web driver based on a key value like you are doing here.  To do this, simply replace this line

```
WebDriver driver = myDriverUtilities.getDriver();
```

with

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Obviously, make sure the path to the `chromedriver.exe` is resolved correctly for your system. By the way, unless your web drivers are in the root folder of your code project, that path is not correct. I will double check that is the case.

I ran your code with this recommendation and it worked. That tells me either your web driver path is not correct, or there is something funky with your `config.properties`.

Lastly, this loop isn't correct either

```
    for (String key : config.stringPropertyNames()) {
        if (key.equals("browser")) {
            driverName = config.getProperty(key);
        }
    }
```

You don't want to loop through all your browser keys. If you have more than one "key", it will iterate through them and return the last one found. Instead, you need to call `getProperty()` once your properties file is loaded:

```
String propValue = props.getProperty("browser");
```

Then, once you have the correct `propValue`, you should pass it to your switch to properly instantiate the web driver.

```
switch(propValue) {
    case "chrome":
        this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
        break;
    case "firefox":
        this.driver = new GeckoDriver();
        break;
    default:
        // throw some exception here
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(propValue + " is not a supported browser.");
}
```